# Random layer malfunction

Tags: creality-ender-3, adhesion, layer-shifting, stringing

When I was printing this part which has this cross-shaped portion in the middle that has supports, it seems that as soon as it started the layer with the supported part, the layer just completely strung everywhere and just went into thin air. If there is any way I would be able to fix this problem, as it seems like it just appeared out of nowhere on an otherwise perfect print, any help would be appreciated. Just so you know I was printing with Overture gray PETG at 235 °C nozzle and 85 °C bed. This was printed on an Ender 3 with a silent motherboard.

[image: Photo of a printed model where the top portion has begun to show stringing]

Comment: did it look ok when previewed on slicer? Can't really tell much from the picture

Comment: Yes it looked fine. In the picture it shows that basically when the layers change after a while it stopped adhering to the layer below it

Comment: I suggest you check the STL for problems. If it was drawn as two objects and then joined, there may be an issue at the join.